# JwtSecurityTokenHandler don't map OIDC claims to Microsoft claims

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, jwt

I have a JWT token which contains OIDC (role) claims. I use the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` to read and parse the token. In my understanding the handler should use the `InboundClaimTypeMap` to map the OIDC claims to the Microsoft claims.

OIDC `role` => Microsoft `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role`

But that doesn't happen, the claims have always the OIDC type. Am I missing something?
Any help is appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var jwt = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJPbmxpbmUgSldUIEJ1aWxkZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE2MjI2MzI4MzYsImV4cCI6MTY1NDE2ODgzNiwiYXVkIjoid3d3LmV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwic3ViIjoianJvY2tldEBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsImdpdmVuX25hbWUiOiJKb2hubnkiLCJzdXJuYW1lIjoiUm9ja2V0IiwiZW1haWwiOiJqcm9ja2V0QGV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwicm9sZSI6WyJNYW5hZ2VyIiwiUHJvamVjdCBBZG1pbmlzdHJhdG9yIl19.eWjHJ3sw1M34tsmBrbAenunx_rRaFRtZW_8TZ--BhAc";
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = handler.ReadJwtToken(jwt);
        
        foreach (var claim in token.Claims)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(claim.Type);
        }
    }
}
```

[Run at .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k85P3G)

Comment: The mapping process is performed at the `ClaimsPrincipal` level; not the token level. The [`ReadJwtToken`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs#L656) method doesn't perform the transformation. For that, you need to use one of the methods that return a `ClaimsPrincipal`, such as `ValidateToken`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's a detail good to know. I will check it out.

Comment: @arkord how did you end up fixing it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember anymore. It's been too long.